How to assign a selinux scontext to an android app
My question is similar to this:
How process under android selinux context was labeled？
except for I'm trying to assign it to an android app. Currently my app is being labelled as a platform_app, which is blocked to some other tcontext due to some neverallow rules. I believe it was assigned that way because I gave it a certificate: "platform",, full build file:
android_app {
    name: "MyApp",
    srcs: [
        "src/**/*.java",
    ],
    resource_dirs: [
        "res/",
    ],
    manifest: "AndroidManifest.xml",
    platform_apis: true,
    installable: true,
    certificate: "platform",
    privileged: true,
}

This is an example log:
04-22 14:07:33.660  2209  2209 I pool-2-thread-1: type=1400 audit(0.0:2203): avc:  denied  { open } for  path="/path/im/trying/to/read" dev="tmpfs" ino=59937 scontext=u:r:platform_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:the_target_context:s0 tclass=file permissive=1 app=com.example.product.MyApp

Say I want to create a new scontext (which I believe I know what to do), how do I assign that scontext to my app?
The problem I'm currently running into is not knowing how to point to the binary that gets run, since the app is a .apk:
/where/to/point/to/my/app   u:object_r:my_new_context:s0


I figured it out!
in sepolicy/ create a new sepolicy/seapp_contexts:
# Add new domain for MyApp
user=_app seinfo=platform name=com.example.product.MyApp
 domain=my_app_service

now you can register and give my_app context the permissions in sepolicy/my_app.te:
type my_app_service, domain;
app_domain(display_monitor_service)

allow my_app_service the_target_context:file open;

